# Convert Range Records

Tags: sql, hana

I have the following scenario and would need some help with the SQL

```
ID  Flag    ValidFrom     Valid To
1    A      2017001       2017005   ( Valid Till end of 2017004)
1    B      2007005       2017008
1    C      2017008       2017012
2    D      2017001       2017006
2    E      2007006       2017008
2    F      2017008       2017012
```

I need result somthing like this

```
1      2017001    A
1      2007002    A
1      2017003    A
1      2017004    A
1      2007005    B
1      2017006    B
1      2017007    B
1      2007008    C
1      2017009    C
1      2017010    C
1      2017011    C
2      2017001    D
2      2007002    D
2      2017003    D
2      2017004    D
2      2007005    D
2      2017006    E
2      2017007    E
2      2007008    F
2      2017009    F
2      2017010    F
2      2017011    F
```

Actually i need the only Min 3 months so i actually need something like this

```
1      2017001    A
1      2007002    A
1      2017003    A
2      2017001    D
2      2007002    D
2      2017003    D
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I could not understand your requirement clearly. Do you want min. 3 months for different ID values? Or Flags with lasting for a 3 month period ?

Comment: Is 2017005 year+month, since there are 7 characters ? Or is it only numeric values?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check following SELECT statement

```
;with cte as (
    select 0 as n union all 
    select 1 as n union all 
    select 2 as n
)
select
    ID,
    Flag,
    ValidFrom,
    case when r.ValidTo - r.ValidFrom > 2 then r.ValidFrom+2 else r.ValidTo end as ValidTo,
    ValidFrom + n as result
from ranges r, cte
where ValidFrom + n <= ValidTo
```